# Does stl library use malloc while copying pointers?

Tags: stl, copy, malloc, shallow-copy

I have a question regarding copying pointers in the stl library. Say I define:

`struct A{
int x;
}`

`std::map<int, const A*> map1;`

I then populate map1 using memory from the heap using malloc for the pointer to A.

Then I do

`std::map<int, const A*> map2 = map1;`

For each pointer of struct A in map2, does std::map do a shallow copy of the pointers, or assign new memory from the heap for each of the pointers?

Cheers

Shanker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will copy just the pointers. That means that a shallow copy will be made as opposed to a deep copy. You can easily check the actual behavior by using a simple test program:

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, int*> map1;        
    map1[0] = new int(10);

    std::map<int, int*> map2 = map1;
    *(map2[0]) = 20;

    // this must print 20 if a shallow copy is used
    std::cout << *(map1[0]) << std::endl;
}
```